# ¿La fecha actualización de Play Store Impacta en las actualizaciones automáticas?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

Hice el lanzamiento de una actualización en la Consola de Google Play aparentemente sin problema alguno. Pero note que en la sección de *Información de la app* de **Play Store** tiene la fecha de actualización diferente (una fecha inferior) y en la sección *Información adicional* de **Google Play** (versión web) me muestra la fecha correcta.

**¿Alguien sabe porque sucede esto y si tiene algún impacto en las actualizaciones automáticas de la app?**

Google Play:

[image: Captura de Google Play]

Play Store:

[image: Captura de Play Store]

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo a lo que comentas:

> note que en la sección de Información de la app de Play Store tiene la
> fecha de actualización diferente (una fecha inferior)

debes saber que **la app Play Store guarda caché y en ocasiones tarda algo de tiempo para actualizar la información**, cuando liberas una app pueden tardar varias horas en actualizarse.

**Te recomiendo elimines la caché de la app Play Store para que veas los datos actualizados!.**